# Capsicum leaves are curling and deforming

Tags: leaves, capsicum-pubsecens

I hope you can help me out. I bought this gorgeous capsicum plant (together with other plants) from local garden shop 10 days ago and planted it into my SFG. We are in Western Australia (Perth). 
After couple of days from planting the leaves in the capsicum started to curl, initially I thought that to be from the shock of replanting but today I took the below pictures and it does not look good. It affected only capsicum plants so far and one of them in particular.

[image]

[image]

The plants are being watered 2 times a day and are in full sun. I fertilised with blood and bone 5 days ago...

It looks like the leaves are curling and deforming. The new levels at the top are wilting and very deformed. Same goes for the new flower buds.

Can someone please help.  Is that calcium deficiency? Or do I water to often, it is hot here at the moment. Or is this a virus and I better pul the plug on them? Help!!

Comment: I think you are watering too much. Don't water until the soil doesn't stick to you finger when you drag it across the surface. BTW what is 'SFG'?

Comment: I think it refers to square foot gardening, where you split your garden into plots and grow things in groups. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It would be good to know what other plants you bought that are not facing this issue. Still, when only one of them suffers, it tells you something. Do you have a pH meter? Your soil ought to be slightly acidic for this guy to be happy.

It appears though, that as you have suggested, calcium deficiency might be one issue. Given the plant's sickness, give it just a moderate quantity right now, if you want to try that. Plus, lime brings UP the pH, which you don't want in excess.

Lastly, sometimes, plants do have one of two transfer problems. The plant may have already been on its last legs just around when you bought it (which is when clever stores will put them on "sale" sometimes) or some plants will go into transfer shock and some just wont recover.

You could try adjusting your watering schedule, check your pH, calcium and sunlight access for the capsicum plant (they love a lot of sun unless it is too harsh, summer for you guys right now I assume) and see how it goes. Right now, unless the plant is in real shade, I would leave it be even if it is not getting too much sun, till it recovers.

Or, at least in the US, a lot of stores will take returns. So you could try returning the plant. I'd do that as a last recourse.